# UICollectionView inside UIScrollView cells disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a strange behaviour of `collectionView` when I change `contentInset` of `scrollView` when the keyboard is appear. And sometimes the cells just disappears, I don't know how this happens.

`self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardRect.height, right: 0)`

[image]

Here is a [test project.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5yFnEzUOYPrOUp5cmd5aTZCR2c) in google drive. I have tested XCode 8.3, iOS 10, Simulator iPhone SE

`automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` doesn't work

Comment: I have same issue. When I try to change collection view height then cell disappear. I dont know what's happening. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that *is* rather odd. When the `scrollView.contentInset` is changed, *or* when the `scrollView` size is changed, the `.contentSize.height` of the embedded `UICollectionView` changes to `32`. I can't figure out why. It doesn't seem to be related to anything else...

I tried loading it as a Child VC and adding it as a subview instead of using "embedded in Container View" method -- same result.

Couple workarounds though (or, if it sounds better, alternate approaches)...

It does *not* appear to happen if the embedded Child VC in the ContainerView is a regular `UIViewController` with a `UICollectionView` added as a subview.

It does *not* appear to happen if you add a Collection View directly to the View Controller, and skip the whole Container View thing.

Comment: Yes, now, I'm using just `UIViewController` with subview `UICollectionView`